# make aosp get Input/output error

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-make, android-source

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/bin/ld: fatal error: out/soong/.intermediates/art/runtime/libartd/linux_glibc_x86_64_shared/libartd.so: Input/output error clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
[ 75% 52732/69665] //art/runtime:libartd link libartd.so [linux_glibc x86] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. 22:37:32 ninja failed with: exit status 1

prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/bin/ld: fatal error: out/soong/.intermediates/art/runtime/libartd/linux_glibc_x86_64_shared/libartd.so: Input/output error
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[  0% 44/16934] host Prebuilt: libartd...RIES/libartd_intermediates/libartd.so)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
23:59:35 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

When I built AOSP under Ubuntu 18.04, I got this error.
I had tried to change the VM, but got this error again.
I also changed the ccache size - still got error.
I Googled but can't find the answer. So what can I do to solve it?

Comment: could be hard disk problem, check your `dmesg` output for scary errors.

Comment: If you want to make your life easier use Ubuntu 14.04 to build AOSP like source.android.com recommends.

Comment: Previously planned to compile on the mobile hard disk, so easy to carry, and now I gave up.
I changed to the local hard drive and it has been successful. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the official documentation recommends 14.04, 18.04 is now also available.Thank you.